# What is the reason of getting a java.lang.NullPointerException in Apache Tomcat 8.5.64?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, nullpointerexception

I am getting `HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error` while executing a `servlet`. The server log is attached below:

```
19-Mar-2021 13:56:27.808 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
19-Mar-2021 13:56:27.808 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
19-Mar-2021 13:56:54.514 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
19-Mar-2021 13:56:54.514 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
19-Mar-2021 13:56:54.516 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@1119e87')
19-Mar-2021 13:57:17.198 SEVERE [http-nio-8081-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke Exception Processing /FARMCON/SendInvoice
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:242)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:616)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1629)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have checked my code logic multiple times but it does not contain any error. The `SendInvoice servlet` generates a PDF invoice & sends it over email. The code I have written is tested & worked previously. I think Tomcat is having some problem but can't trace it out. Please help!

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask]. And post the full stacktrace (as mentioned in Tomcat's message): It might have a root cause that points to the actual line where the NPE appears.

Comment: @OlafKock sorry for my mistake. I have removed the image & but server log is already there. Please help!

Comment: No root cause in the logs?

Comment: @OlafKock sorry but I did not find any. Perhaps I am looking in the wrong space. Can you please elaborate on how to check the root cause? I am actually a beginner in the field of developing web applications. Thanks!

Comment: In the Tomcat logs you should find the root cause right after this exception. Without, it's impossible to answer, there's none of your code in there. You might also want to post any nonstandard configuration and make this a [mcve]